# Updating JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working on a PHP script to add new item in JSON array (JSON is in a file) and I've found a prob and its solution. My question is: can someone explains why the first code doesn't work?

The JSON is built on several imbricated arrays describing batiments, stairs and objects on each stair of each batiment:

```
"bats":[
   // each batiment
  {"name":"Bat A","photo":"photo-bat-0.png",
   "stairs":[
       // level 0
       {"plan":"plan-0-0.png","note":"",
        "objs":[
          {"id":"obj-0-0-0","type":"MER","col":"black","left":"","top":"","cable":22,"img":""},
          {"id":"obj-0-0-1","type":"SER","col":"blue","left":"","top":"","cable":12,"img":""}
         ],
       },
       // level 1
       {"plan":"plan-0-1.png","note":"",
        "objs":[
          {"id":"obj-0-1-0","type":"TFT","col":"red","left":"","top":"","cable":8,"img":""},
          {"id":"obj-0-1-1","type":"AP1","col":"green","left":"","top":"","cable":12,"img":""},
          {"id":"obj-0-1-2","type":"AP2","col":"green","left":"","top":"","cable":14,"img":""}
         ]
       }
    ]   
 }, 
 {"name":"Bat B","photo":"photo-bat-1.png"
   "stairs":[
    ...
```

Adding a new object to BAT 1 LEVEL 0:

```
$bat = 1;
$lev = 0;

// get existing objects
$objects = $json_data['bats'][$bat]['stairs'][$lev]['objs'];

$n = count($objects);

echo "found $n objects on level $lev of bat $bat<br>";
for($o=0; $o<count($objects); $o++){
    echo $objects[$o]['id']."<br>";
}
```

The object to add to array

```
$newobject = array("id"=>"obj-".$bat."-".$lev."-".$o,"type"=>"AP","coul"=>"green","left"=>123,"top"=>155,"cable"=>5,"img"=>"image-obj-".$bat."-".$lev."-".$o);
```

This code doesn't work: (JSON file remains the same once reloaded)

```
array_push($objects,$newobject);
```

This one works: (JSON file updated)

```
array_push($json_data['bats'][$bat]['stairs'][$lev]['objs'],$newobject);
```

Why is it necessary to recreate the full access path to array 'objs'?

Comment: Because $objects is a copy. It doesn't reference the original array.

Comment: but it works when I echo the result $objects[$o] in the loop. So the path to access to info is right, no?

Comment: So? You're working on a copy of the data. Anything you change in the copy will change as you expect, and reading changed values from the copy will also work, because that's where you made the change, but working on a copy has no effect on the original.

Comment: OK, understood :) Thanks.